# "Fatal: too many params" when calling bash command from python, no error using same command directly in git bash

Tags: python, bash, git, subprocess, git-bash

Expanding on a previously working function, I ran into a problem with the $(echo -e"...")-part, subprocess.call returns "fatal: too many params".

If i copy the printed bashCmd and paste it directly in Git Bash, I end up with the expected result (new tag created with heading, and some formatted presentation of the "body" of the tag; "new functions: ... \n bugfixes: ...\n" etc.

The printed bashCmd string passed as argument to subprocess.call:
`git tag -a v1.4.9 -m "new tag description" -m"$(echo -e "==New Features==\n  no new features\n  but feature 1\n  and feature 2\n==Bugfixes==\n  fixed whitespace\n  hopefully it works\n==Known Issues==\n  No Known Issues Reported.\n")"`

```
bashCmd = 'git tag -a v' + str(major) + '.' + str(minor) + '.' + str(bugfix) +' -m'+ ''' "''' + heading + '''" '''+'-m'+ '''"$(echo -e'''+ ''' "'''  +body+'''"''' ''')"'''

subprocess.call(bashCmd, shell=True)
print(bashCmd)
```

Comment: Why `$(echo -e $body)` when you can just pass `$body` without `$()`?

Comment: *too many params* means there is an excessive space(s) somewhere, most probably in that `body`.

Comment: There are two spaces after each \n, is that an issue? For git bash, or for subprocess.call? I know next to nothing about bash scripting, but from a quick google search I think i need to use echo -e to handle the \n newlines? I tried with different bashCmd without any double spaces, but same result: `git tag -a v1.4.9 -m "tag description" -m"$(echo -e "==New Features==\nonly one feature this time\n==Bugfixes==\nNo Bugfixes Reported.\n==Known Issues==\nNo Known Issues Reported.\n")"`

Comment: Using string concatenation to form shell commands is a major source of security bugs. Do not do so, **ever** -- see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection for a high-level overview, and https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Command_Injection for a less-generic / more-focused reference. Chepner's answer is safe, because it's keeping code and data out-of-band from each other. Any answer that concatenates strings together and passes the result as content for a shell to execute is innately suspect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason for using the shell here. Use the list form for the first argument to `call`. Note this will require you to modify `body`, but that will
make it *simpler*.

```
body = """\
==New Features==
still not working

==Bugfixes==
0 bugs fixed

==Known Issues==
infinite amounts of bugs left"""

commit_msg = "heading\n\n" + body
version_str = '.'.join(['v', str(major), str(minor), str(bugfix)]),

git_cmd = [
    'git', 
    'tag',
    '-a',
    version_str,
    '-m',
    commit_msg
]


subprocess.call(git_cmd)
```

Comment: Thank you @chepner, this worked. Not sure I totally understands why, but for now at least the formatting appears correctly in github.